# Autoconversion from number to NULL

Tags: r

I am trying to generate a vector of random numbers based on a finite random variable X [image]

With probGen function I generate a variable X, l1 is the first line and l2 is the second one.
And at this point `if(sum1 >= U)` I recive this error `Error in if (sum1 >= U) { : argument is of length zero`

This is my code:

```
probGen=function(n)
{
  v=vector()
  k=sample(1:n,1)
  v=rep(0,k)
  for(i in 1:n)
  {
    aux=sample(1:k,1)
    v[aux]=v[aux]+1
  }
  vfinal=vector()
  klen=0
  for(i in 1:k)
  {
    if(v[i]!=0) klen=klen+1
  }
  for(i in 1:k)
  {
    if(v[i]!=0)
      vfinal=c(vfinal,rep(1/(klen*v[i]),v[i]))
  }
  vfinal=sample(vfinal)
  return (vfinal)
}

n=22
l1=c(1:n)
l2=probGen(n)
l1
l2

simVar=function(l1,l2)
{
  variante=vector()
  U=runif(1,0,1)
  for(i in 1:length(l1))
  {
    sum1=1-1
    for(j in 1:i-1)
    {
      if(i-1>=1)
      {
        sum1=sum1+l2[j]
      }
    }
    sum2=0.0
    for(j in 1:i)
    {
      sum2=sum2+l2[j]
    }

    if(sum1 >= U)
    {
      if(U<sum2)
      {
        variante=c(variante,l1[i])
      }
    }
  }


  return (variante)
}

varR=simVar(l1,l2)
varR
```

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Please put a `set.seed(..)` for replicability with random numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for(j in 1:i-1)` near the top of the code for `simVar` is evaluating as `(1:i)-1`, resulting in a zero j which produces a `NA` value of `sum1`.  Use `for(j in 1:(i-1))` instead.